# Audition - Auto-Tune to song

Tags: adobe-audition, pitch, autotune

I am trying to change the pitch (autotune) to song. * I have audio of someone speaking, and I want to change the pitch to a melody of a song.

Can anyone help me? The normal pitch correction only shifts the tones to nearest level...

This is a (great) example: https://www(DOT)youtube.com/watch?v=fR9ClX0egTc

Comment: That's not Autotune, it's a [vocoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocoder)

Comment: Omg thank you. You can add this as an answer if you want.